# jQuery setting onclick attr of another element

Tags: jquery, onclick

i want to set the onclick attribute of another element by klicking on the first one but i can't get it working.
Here is my sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/bssqgprg/

```
<a id="a1" onclick='$("#a2").attr("onclick", "window.prompt("Text:","foo")");'>test</a>
<a id="a2">test</a>
```

Comment: use jQuery event handlers instead of inlined one... your string concatenation is not proper

Comment: `<a id="a1" onclick='$("#a2").attr("onclick", "window.prompt(\"Text:\",\"foo\")");'>test</a>` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bssqgprg/2/

Comment: Try your update `FIDDLE` in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery

```js
$(function() {
  //use one since you want to bind it only once
  $('#a1').one('click', function() {
    $('#a2').click(function() {
      window.prompt('Text:', 'foo');
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="a1">test</a>
<a id="a2">test</a>
```

Comment: Why did you stay both `<a id="a1" onclick="` and `$('#a1').one('click'` in code? It actually results in two prompts.

Comment: @Regent yes... forgot to remove that

Answer (score 1):

you have to escape double quotes

```
<a id="a1" onclick='$("#a2").attr("onclick", "window.prompt(\"Text:\",\"foo\")");'>test</a>
```

**Explanation**

```
attr("onclick", "window.prompt("// your code is like this
$("#a2").attr("onclick", "window.prompt("); // so your code get interpret like this.
```

mean you are closing attribute before circular bracket, code after that cause syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

`'$("#a2").attr("onclick", "window.prompt("Text:","foo")");'` is invalid string (`"` before `window` interferes with `"` before `Text` as so on).

You can use `click` event handlers in proper jQuery way:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bssqgprg/1/).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#a1').click(function()
    {
        $("#a2").off("click");
        $("#a2").click(function()
        {
            prompt('Text:','foo');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try your updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bssqgprg/5/)

```
   $("#a1").click(function(){
       $("#a2").attr({"onclick":"window.prompt(\"Text:\",\"foo\")"});
       alert($("#a2").attr("onclick"));
   });
```

Comment: Mixing outdated `onclick=""` with jQuery event handlers is not a good idea.

Comment: I am setting the attribute `onclick` . I am not messing it with jQuery event handlers

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean "mixing". Seriously, if you can use `$("#a2").click(function() { prompt('Text:','foo'); });`, why would you want to stay with manual setting of `onclick` attribute? Yes, it is in OP question, but I suppose it is good to show how code should look like without clumsy outdated `onclick`.